# How can I convert my SQL command to a lambda expression?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda, nhlambdaextensions

I have SQL Query like this :

```
  select top 1 Newsletter_HTML_Tag  from Newsletter_TBL
     where (Newsletter_Category_ID=1)
     order by Creation_Date desc
```

and I also have a method which give me the list of all records from `Newsletter_TBL` named:

> NewsletterGellAll()

and I have tried it before, but it doesn't work:

```
NewsletterGellAll()
   .FirstOrDefault(c => c.NEWSLETTER_CATEGORY_ID == 1)
   .orderby(a => a.Creation_Date)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: _"it doesn't work"_ is meaningless.

Comment: Is it GetAllNewsLetter() or NewsLetterGetAll()?  Also, what error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

First query all items with cat==1, then order it to get the first

```
NewsletterGellAll().Where(c=>c.NEWSLETTER_CATEGORY_ID==1)
                   .OrderBy(a=>a.Creation_Date)
                   .First();
```

Comment: This might throw an exception when there will be no records with category==1

Answer (score 0):

It should be `OrderByDescending` instead of `OrderBy` if you want to replicate the results for the SQL Query.

Additionally, if you look at your query:

```
NewsletterGetAll()
.FirstOrDefault(c => c.NEWSLETTER_CATEGORY_ID == 1)
.OrderBy(a => a.Creation_Date)
```

In SQL this would be ok, since it evaluates the `ORDER BY` before the `TOP` expression. However, in Linq it will take the first record that matches the category, and then order that single record. So this won't even build, you cannot sort a single item.

Therefore it should be

```
NewsletterGetAll()
.Where(c => c.NEWSLETTER_CATEGORY_ID == 1)
.OrderByDescending(c => c.Creation_Date)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always advisable to use First or Default when you are not sure that condition will not be satisfied, as this will also handle null case. Means, if there are no records (with specific condition).

Depends of order to Date as well, here consider that date is ascending, (older date first)

```
NewsletterGellAll().Where(c=>c.NEWSLETTER_CATEGORY_ID==1)
                    .OrderBy(a=>a.Creation_Date)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: how i can add .ToList() to your code? Is there any way?

Comment: ToList() is used when a List is returned, since you will get only one record, so First or Default is used here.

Answer (score 0):

use LINQPad and make professional LINQ and SQL queries. here is [linqpad](https://www.linqpad.net/)

Comment: This is not a good practice, you must know the conversion for better learning.